# list内のlistだけを指定順序で整列

Tags: python, python3

python上で

```
lst=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,],[1,2,3]]
```

が用意されていて
それを

```
lst=[[2,3,1],[2,3,1],[2,3,1],[2,3,1]]
```

にソートしたいです。
リストうちの要素の中身だけをユーザの指定順序でソートするには
どのようにしたらよいでしょうか

Comment: 指定順序、はどのように指定することを考えていますか（例えば、`[1,  0, 2]` など、対応するインデックスを指定など？）？ / ちなみに、 `list` は組み込み関数ですので、この名前で変数を代入するのはおすすめしません。

Comment: また、リストの中身が `[[1, 2], [3, 4,  5, 6]]` のように、要素数が少なかったり多かったりする場合は想定していますか？

Comment: 順序の指定はリストのインデックスを指定（順序を指定した別のlist）を扱うつもりでした。

Comment: 配列要素はすべて統合しています。要素がなければダミーを与えています。

Comment: numpy を使っても良いのであれば、`import numpy as np` として、`np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[[1,2,0]], 1, np.array(lst)).tolist()` とすることもできます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

子リスト要素数が固定であり、外部から要素ソート順`order`を与えるパターンです：

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
order = [2,0,1]

result = []
for sublist in data:
    result.append( [pack[1] for pack in sorted(zip(order, sublist))] )
```

上記をまとめて、リスト内包表記のネストでも記述は可能です（可読性は微妙ですが...）

```
result = [[pack[1] for pack in sorted(zip(order, sublist))] for sublist in data]
```

Comment: FYI: 質問文中では「リスト内包表記」という単語を誤解されているようです。[リスト内包表記は、括弧の中の式、for 句、そして0個以上のforかif句で構成されます](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました。質問文訂正させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

たかだか3つなら

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,],[1,2,3]]
lst = [[j, k, i] for i, j, k in lst]
```

とするでしょう。

そうでないなら
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter
を使って、

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,],[1,2,3]]

getter = itemgetter(1, 2, 0)
lst = [list(getter(x)) for x in lst]
```

とでもします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問文ではlistという変数名を使っていましたが実際のコードではつかっていません。質問文を訂正いたしました。

Comment: 了解です。回答の方も編集して該当部分を消しました。